# Jenkins CasC handling tokens Configurations As Code

Tags: jenkins, groovy, bitbucket, token, configuration-as-code

I've been trying to provide some tokens through CasC (BitBucket Plugin) but every time the Jenkins instance restarted then the tokens are not working.
As I see that is happening  because Jenkins use different salt and the Hash is changing.
How i can provide in groovy the token in order to produce the secret ?

Comment: Can you share you Config As Code?

Answer (score 0):

I dont use BitBucket but here is how I do this for Slack

```
---
credentials:
  system:
    domainCredentials:
      - credentials:
          - string:
              description: "Slack auth token"
              scope: GLOBAL
              id: "slack-token"
              secret: ${slack-token}

unclassified:
  slackNotifier:
    teamDomain: "apr-1985-slack-space"
    tokenCredentialId: slack-token
```

This is using the AWS SSM plugin to pull the credential out of the Parameter Store and add them to Jenkins.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have do the following without success!
`  credentials:
      system:
        domainCredentials:
        - credentials:
          - bitbucketToken:
              id: "bitbucket-token"
              secret: ${bitbucket-token}
      bitbucketPluginConfiguration:
        serverList:
        - adminCredentialsId: "bitbucket-token"
          baseUrl: "http://hostname/bitbucket"
          id: "my-token-here"
          serverName: "bitbucket"  `